# Spring webflow - Can't define global-transitions

Tags: spring-webflow

I can't seem to define any global transitions in flow definition file. As soon as I define a global-transition, I am getting exceptions.

Here is the flow definition

my-flow.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <flow xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow" 
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
       xsi:schemaLocation="
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow
              http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow/spring-webflow-2.0.xsd">

<!-- set up appData initial values -->
     <on-start>
         <evaluate expression="SupportUtil.setUpInitialAppData(flowRequestContext)" result="flowScope.appData"/>    
     </on-start>

     <global-transitions>
        <transition on="login" to="login" />
        <transition on="logout" to="logout" />
      </global-transitions>

      <view-state id="searchHome" view="searchHome" model="searchModel">
            <transition on="grpSearch" to="performGrpSearch"/>
             <transition on="indSearch" to="performIndSearch"/>
       </view-state> 
  </flow>
```

Once I start the app, I get following error,

> org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.FlowBuilderException:
>   Unable to get the model for this flow     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.model.FlowModelFlowBuilder.doInit(FlowModelFlowBuilder.java:149)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.support.AbstractFlowBuilder.init(AbstractFlowBuilder.java:46)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.FlowAssembler.assembleFlow(FlowAssembler.java:90)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.DefaultFlowHolder.assembleFlow(DefaultFlowHolder.java:109)
>     ... 37 more Caused by:
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.model.builder.FlowModelBuilderException:
>   Could not parse the XML flow definition document at ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/flows/tempId-flow.xml]     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.model.builder.xml.XmlFlowModelBuilder.init(XmlFlowModelBuilder.java:121)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.model.builder.DefaultFlowModelHolder.assembleFlowModel(DefaultFlowModelHolder.java:87)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.model.builder.DefaultFlowModelHolder.getFlowModel(DefaultFlowModelHolder.java:61)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.builder.model.FlowModelFlowBuilder.doInit(FlowModelFlowBuilder.java:146)
>     ... 40 more Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException:
>   cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: **Invalid content was found starting with
>   element 'view-state'. One of
>   '{"http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":on-end,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":output,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":exception-handler,
>   "http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow":bean-import}' is
>   expected.     at**
>   org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)  at
>   javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.model.builder.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:113)
>     at
>   org.springframework.webflow.engine.model.builder.xml.XmlFlowModelBuilder.init(XmlFlowModelBuilder.java:113)
>     ... 43 more

Part of the exception in bold letters is really confusing to me. Why is that only those elements are expected. I have used the latest flow definition schema from the reference tutorials

http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/ch03s05.html  and http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/2.3.x/reference/html/ch10s02.html

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I got the element sequence wrong.  should be after all the  definitions.